# Powershell subsequent usernames

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I just started learning Powershell and I was wondering how to make a powershell script that scans the OU for users and picks the subsequent number. For example when I have a "User1" and "User2" in my OU it will create "User3" when I run the script

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and include these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find a pre-packaged script but in your case you have a specific requirement so the best advice is that you build your own script. A good starting point could be the following code block from a friend in the powershell community:

```
$lastUser = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=name,DC=domain,DC=com' |
    Where-Object SamAccountName -match '(\d+)$' |
    Sort-Object { [Int]$matches[1] } |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

This won't satisfy your requirement completely but can help you get there. Hope it helps!